# I understood the Redux state being made available to the container but how are the action creators available to the containers via props,

Tags: react-redux

// How is a an action creator made available to the container in the props when it is not present in the redux state?

```
//This is my action creator

export function latestNews(){
  const request = fetch(`${URL}/articles?_order=desc&_end=3`, {method:'GET'})
      .then(response => response.json());
  return {
      type: 'GET_LATEST',
      payload: request
    }

}

//Below is my container's lifecycle method
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.latestNews();
};



//How can I access my action creator through props? I want to understand the concept
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import actions from your action file using import statement. And connect your redux store to your component and in Mount method do like below -
this.props.dispatch(latestNews());

For more clarity please share complete code.